# Discrete Mathematics - Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

A student has 5 weeks to prepare for their midterm test. The student's friend has volunteered to tutor them for either 15min or 30min every day until the test but not for more than 15 hours total. Show that during some period of consecutive days, the student and their tutor will study for exactly $8 \frac{3}{4}$ hours.

I believe that questions of this sort have been asked before on this forum but, I still do not seem to understand how the answers were derived and how they were able to come up with the functions they used.

I understand what the question is asking for but am really struggling to come up with what the pigeons are and what the pigeonholes are in this scenario. If anyone could please give a simple explanation as to what they are it would be much appreciated. I feel like if I understand where they come from then I will be able to complete this question.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Yours Truly,

A struggling student in need of help

Comment: @Arthur as I mentioned before I have tried to understand some of these solutions before but cannot seem to wrap my head around it. If there is any way to possibly simplify the readability of the solution it would be appreciated!

Comment: The answer in the marked duplicate is quite clear. And there are many pigeonhole questions on this site, there is no way for us to tell whether you have seen that exact post. If you instead ask about specific clarifications to that answer, then this stops being a duplicate, and we will be much better equipped to tell you what you _actually_ want us to tell you. But until you make such a revision to your question, the best we can do to answer your question is to repeat the answer in the other thread. And that's best done through a duplicate tag.